# JSOUP Deleting closing and/or opening divs only

Tags: java, html, parsing, dom, jsoup

Hello Im googling for hours now and can't find answer...(or smt close to it)
What i am trying to do is, lets say i have this code(very simplified):

```
<div id="one"><div id="two"><div id="three"></div></div></div>
```

And what i want to do is delete specific amount of this elements , lets say 2 of them. So the result would be:

```
<div id="one"><div id="two"><div id="three"></div>
```

Or i want to delete this opening elements (again specific amount of them, lets say 2 again)  but without knowing their full name (so we can assume if real name is id="one_54486464" i know its one_ ... )
So after deleting I get this result:

```
<div id="three"></div></div></div>
```

Can anyone suggest way to achieve this results? It does not have to Include JSOUP, any better. more simple or more efficient way is welcomed :) (But i am using JSOUP to parse document to get to the point where i am left with )
I hope i explain myself clearly if you have any question please do ask... Thanks :)

EDIT: Those elements  that i want to delete are on very end of the HTML document(so nothing, nothing is behind them not body tag html tag nothing...)
Please keep that HTML document would have many  across whole code and i want to delete only specific amount at the end of the document...

For the opening divs  THOSE are on very beginning of my HTML document and nothing is before them... So i need to remove specific amount from the beginning without knowing their specific ID only start of it. Also this div has closing too somewhere in the document and that closing i want to keep there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first case, you can get the element's html (using the `html()` method) and use some `String` methods on it to delete a couple of its closing tags.

Example:

```
e.html().replaceAll("(((\\s|\n)+)?<\\/div>){2}$","");
```

This will remove the last 2 closing `div` tags, to change the number of tags to be remove, just change the number between the curly brackets `{n}`

(this is just an example and is probably unreliable, you should use some other `String` methods to decide which parts to discard)

For the second case, you can select the inner element(s) and add some additional closing tags to it/them.

Example:

```
String s = e.select("#two").first().html() + "</div></div>";
```

To select an element that has an ID that starts with some `String` you can use this `e.select("div[id^=two]")`

You can find more details on [how to select elements here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I forget to say that what that example i showed is only fragment when you write  replace </div> for " " i am replacing every div in html not only those who i want ... I also forget to say that i </div> i want to delete are on very ending of html code(so, nothing is behind them)... 
To the second i want delete that opening divs not close them... i cant close, i need them gone :)

Comment: @Pauli For the first example, `html()` returns a `String` which means the the `replace(...)` method is not replacing elements, it is only discarding the `"</div></div>"` `String`.

Comment: @Pauli For the second example, you don't have to discard the opening `div`s, you can select the inner elements of the `div` and add some extra closing tags to them.

Comment: Hi, I want to delete them for other reason that i dont want to explain because it would get too complicated to understand, i really need them gone not closed, And like i said there would be plenty of </div> not only this that i want to delete so i cant use replace... I want something that would allow me to delete specified amount of </div> at the end of a page

Comment: @Pauli I've edited my answer, see if you can do this by using `replaceAll(...)` , the regex that I've used should discard the last 2 closing `div` tags.

Comment: Hey Thanks, i tried that but it doesnt work and cuz i dont understand regular expression well enough im not really able to edit it right now (but i  will look into that and try something) what i tried and doesnt work:
`code
String code = "<div id='zmaz'><div id='nechaj'></div></div>";
System.out.println(code.replaceAll("<\\/div>(.|\n)+?<\\/div>$","")); `

Comment: @Pauli I've corrected the regex, it should work now.

Comment: Yep it works, great but i still need to dynamically change amount of div to be deleted, but im guessing that i can dynamically create regex... So thanks i will look into regular expression now and find out how to do that :)

Comment: @Pauli I've edited my answer again, I've included a way that lets you specify the number of closing tags that should be removed.

Comment: thanks Titus, you are great (you really can leave something that i can figure out :D ) Now only for deleting starting divs <div id="one">, that are located on the very begging of the html document

Answer (score 0):

After Titus suggested regular expressions I decided to write regex for deleting opening divs too. 
So I convert Jsoup Document to String then did the parsing on a string and then convert back to Jsoup Document so I can use Jsoup functions.

ADD: What I was doing is that I was parsing and connecting two pages to one seamless. So there was no missing opening div or closing... so my HTML code stay with no errors therefore I was able to convert it back to Jsoup Document without complications.